# Sending packets from wireshark to audio decoder: Is .raw file array of RTP packets?

Tags: c#, buffer, decode, voip, wireshark

I have captured RTP packets and need to decode the packets/sesssion with G.729.1 Decoder. In wireshark, I filtered the RTP packets, analyzed and saved the session as .raw file.
I am using c# streamdecoder for decoding. Its sample provides example how the speech is encoded, saved in buffer and decoded packet by packet. This is the  point I am stuck:

```
const Codec usedCodec = Codec.G7291;  
const int usedSampleRate = 8000;     
const int usedBitrate = 12200; 

var dec = new SpeechDecoder();
dec.SetCodec(usedCodec);
dec.Bitrate = usedBitrate;
```

Now in sample it takes data from the buffer as :

```
var win = new WaveInput();
var samples = win.GetNextSamples().Buffer.Array;
bytescollected += samples.Length;
var frame = enc.EncodeToFrame(samples); //enc is enc = new speechEncoder();
if (frame != null)
{
    // decode byte stream
    var packet = frame.GetNextPacket();
    var raw = dec.Decode(packet);
}
```

My problem is how can I send my .raw file, already saved in desktop for decoding ?

Comment: Can you save the stream to a file and post some sample data?  It is easier to debug these type problems when you can see the actual text data.  Later you can eliminate the file.

Comment: Can you decode raw locally without sending the file?

Comment: @jdweng, Because the packets I captured is encoded using G729.1, and there is no other available decoder tool, I cannot decode it.
I have decoded another packet, which was encoded with G.729, using the codec from voiceage decoder. But not this one.

Comment: @jdweng, This is the sample code from streamcoders library, which encodes the real time speech and decode it.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/iibitassignment2013/files/ProgramF/?

You can see, here the packet is taken from the buffer and decoded. I need to send the packets not from the buffer, but from my saved file.
Thanks

Comment: did you post the .raw file?

Comment: @jdweng, yes. Please check the sample.raw. thanks

Comment: will look at it soon as a get some time today.

Comment: See following webpage : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19842.how-to-play-flac-files-in-windows-phone-using-c.aspx The 2nd link on the page may be what you are looking for.